# How to secure an outdoor 1" PVC 3ft long watering riser pipe?

Tags: water, pipe, outdoor, pvc, outdoorfaucet

How can I secure a ~3ft 1" white PVC pipe riser from getting snapped off?

Riser presently is 6ft up and capped.
I plan to add right angle elbow, valve, and spout (standard lawn house threaded).

Gory Details...
18" below ground riser connects 90 degree elbow that runs 1" white PVC pipe through 18" deep buried trench 75ft to pressurized (60psi) well water supply.

I've thought of a couple of rebar stakes on either side of riser, but directly below riser, 18" down, a gray 3/4" electrical 110vac conduit also runs along same trench, parallel with and touching the 1" water PVC.

Gray elec conduit runs a few feet past water riser and elbows upward to an outlet box, also for my wife's beloved chickens.

I installed trench with 1" white PVC pipe for bringing pressurized well water near to chicken coop.

I've thought of a wooden stake about a foot on either side of water riser.  But chickens will jump on them and crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4x4 treated wood (or concrete for the ultimate) post, 24" (or more) deep beside the pipe (thus beside, not through, the conduit as well) Pipe fastened to post and painted to prevent sun damage. If the present pipe has been left unpainted in the sun for any significant time, it may already be damaged and need to be replaced. Metal T-post for the low-end post option, I guess, but you need to dig at least to the conduit before driving the post.

Alternatively, and pretty much required if you live where it freezes, transition to metal pipe below ground with a galvanized (or stainless for the ultimate) pipe riser and a frost-proof hydrant (drains below ground when shut off. Valve and bleed to drain the riser when shut off are below frost line. Valve handle is up top.)

[image: Frost proof hydrant illustration from Simmons Mfg, example, no endorsement implied]

Comment: Encasing the pressurized pipe in a larger diameter PVC or similar pipe provides protection against elements and trauma.   When protecting in-service pipes, I will sometimes run a slit along the length of the larger pipe so the pipe is not taken out of service: this is unnecessary in the OP's case as the end has not been outfitted with a fixture.  I also like Ecnerwal's idea of pinning the pipe to a wooden post

Answer (score 1):

Cut the pipe a little shorter, say 2 feet instead of 3.   Pile rocks or concrete blocks around it.  8 inch concrete blocks stacked 2-high leaving 8 inches of pipe exposed should protect it from most snappy offy events.  An artistic pyramid of rocks might do even better.   Anything rock-like will scare away careless drivers of mowers, tractors etc.  And anything that leaves no more than 12 inches exposed should protect it from rough handling when attaching hoses.  What else are you worried about?

Comment: +1 for "snappy offy" events. ;)